# How can I use Public IP address and VM in different locations in azure?

Tags: azure, geolocation

I would like to have USA location Public IP for my VM which is located in Europe, is it possible for Azure? If yes, how could I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The public IP must reside in the same location as the resource it is attached to. So it is not easily possible to create a VM in one region, and have the public IP in another.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/associate-public-ip-address-vm

> The public IP addresses that appear are those that exist in the same region as the VM.

You can however host a service in one region, e.g. an [Azure Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview), and have that service redirect all traffic to your VM in another region. You will need a couple of resources to achieve that.

- Standard load balancer in the US region ([basic will not work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-faq#what-are-the-constraints-related-to-global-vnet-peering-and-load-balancers))
- Public IP assigned to load balancer
- VNet  in the US region
- VNet in the Europe region
- VM in the Europe region (no public IP required in Europe)
- VNet Peering between the two VNets